# customize the bibtex output

Tags: natbib, apa-style

The MWE of my code is shown below

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true}

\begin{document}

    Here initial concepts\citep{hocman1988chemoprevention} and conditions are explained and
    several hypothesis\citep{defendi1955quantitative} are mentioned in brief.   \citep{kristan2009new} did the initial work in this area. But in Struss' work \citep{vukovic1993identification}  the definitive model is seen \citep{Ratnakarthesis}.

    \bibliographystyle{apa}
    \bibliography{sample.bib}

\end{document}
```

The content of `sample.bib` is

```
@article{hocman1988chemoprevention,
    title={Chemoprevention of cancer: selenium},
    author={Hocman, Gabriel},
    journal={International Journal of Biochemistry},
    volume={20},
    number={2},
    pages={123--132},
    year={1988},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{defendi1955quantitative,
    title={Quantitative estimation of succinic dehydrogenase activity in a single microscopic tissue section},
    author={Defendi, Vittorio and Pearson, Bjarne},
    journal={Journal of Histochemistry \& Cytochemistry},
    volume={3},
    number={1},
    pages={61--69},
    year={1955},
    publisher={SAGE Publications Sage UK: London, England}
}

@article{kristan2009new,
    title={New high-throughput fluorimetric assay for discovering inhibitors of UDP-N-acetylmuramyl-L-alanine: D-glutamate (MurD) ligase},
    author={Kristan, Katja and Kotnik, Miha and Oblak, Marko and Urleb, Uro{\v{s}}},
    journal={Journal of biomolecular screening},
    volume={14},
    number={4},
    pages={412--418},
    year={2009},
    publisher={Sage Publications}
}

@incollection{vukovic1993identification,
    title={Identification of natural antimutagens with modulating effects on DNA repair},
    author={Vukovi{\'c}-Ga{\v{c}}i{\'c}, Branka and Simi{\'c}, Draga},
    booktitle={Antimutagenesis and Anticarcinogenesis Mechanisms III},
    pages={269--277},
    year={1993},
    publisher={Springer}
}

@PhdThesis{Ratnakarthesis,
    author = {Ratnakar, P.},
    title  = {Biochemical studies of Allium sativum Linn.(Garlic)},
    school = {Delhi University},
    year   = {1992},
    type   = {Ph.D Thesis},
}
```

Its output is

[image]

But according to my university guidelines,the bibliography should be like below[image]

So my requirements are

1.Remove the bracket from year [Eg. (1955) to 1955 ]

2.Change the journal name to regular type instead of italic type [*Journal of biomolecular screening* to Journal of biomolecular screening].

Anybody please help me.

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex`? It's easier to customise.

Comment: @Bernad : My template has already modelled for bibtex

Comment: @Bernad:Anyway How it is possible in BibLaTeX.Please explain. Let me try to change my thesis to BibLaTeX

Comment: You can use Biblatex with the `natbib` compatibility mode. So unless you are working on a submission for publication, switching might not be much work.

Comment: @Bernad: I am on final submission stage of my thesis. Please help me customize with Bibtex

Comment: before you go on customising **.bst** files, did you consider trying out different bibliography styles ? why did you pick apa ?

Comment: @RenjthVRavi: I've posted a solution with `biblatex`. Please see if it's OK for you.

Comment: @Elad Den: APA seems similarity with my university's style

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, giveninits, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
  @article{hocman1988chemoprevention,
    title={Chemoprevention of cancer: selenium},
    author={Hocman, Gabriel},
    journal={International Journal of Biochemistry},
    volume={20},
    number={2},
    pages={123--132},
    year={1988},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{defendi1955quantitative,
    title={Quantitative estimation of succinic dehydrogenase activity in a single microscopic tissue section},
    author={Defendi, Vittorio and Pearson, Bjarne},
    journal={Journal of Histochemistry \& Cytochemistry},
    volume={3},
    number={1},
    pages={61--69},
    year={1955},
    publisher={SAGE Publications Sage UK: London, England}
}

@article{kristan2009new,
    title={New high-throughput fluorimetric assay for discovering inhibitors of UDP-N-acetylmuramyl-L-alanine: D-glutamate (MurD) ligase},
    author={Kristan, Katja and Kotnik, Miha and Oblak, Marko and Urleb, Uro{\v{s}}},
    journal={Journal of biomolecular screening},
    volume={14},
    number={4},
    pages={412--418},
    year={2009},
    publisher={Sage Publications}
}

@incollection{vukovic1993identification,
    title={Identification of natural antimutagens with modulating effects on DNA repair},
    author={Vukovi{\'c}-Ga{\v{c}}i{\'c}, Branka and Simi{\'c}, Draga},
    booktitle={Antimutagenesis and Anticarcinogenesis Mechanisms III},
    pages={269--277},
    year={1993},
    publisher={Springer}
}

@PhdThesis{Ratnakarthesis,
    author = {Ratnakar, P.},
    title = {Biochemical studies of Allium sativum Linn.(Garlic)},
    school = {Delhi University},
    year = {1992},
    type = {Ph.D Thesis},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xpatch}
 \xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
\printtext[parens]
 }{%
\printtext}{}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}

\setlength{\bibhang}{3.5em}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true}

\begin{document}

    Here initial concepts\citep{hocman1988chemoprevention} and conditions are explained and
    several hypothesis\citep{defendi1955quantitative} are mentioned in brief. \citep{kristan2009new} did the initial work in this area. But in Struss' work \citep{vukovic1993identification} the definitive model is seen \citep{Ratnakarthesis}.

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In last reference some italics is shown

Comment: That is the normal behaviour: it's the title of a book. You want book titles in roman too?

Comment: Also, only year is hyperlinked in the text

Comment: Ive solved the book title problem. For the hyperlink problem, I don't have time at the moment, I'll seek for a solution later today.

Comment: @RenjthVRavi: Finally, I had time for a solution. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Bernad :Sorry,  It is not working on my system.I am using TeX Studio and TexLive.I got the following error message.                         
 "This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s) "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60350/discussion-between-renjth-v-ravi-and-bernard).

Comment: @Bernad : Could you please help me

Comment: @RenjthVRavi: You didn't  notice the option `backend=biber` for `biblatex`. This means you must launch `biber`, not `bibtex`.

Comment: @Bernad : The MWE is working. but it is not working in the Thesis

Comment: Then you should post a minimal non-working code that reproduces what happens with your full document.

Comment: @Bernad : It is uploaded,Please see https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Crp_2RrjuPZm4tNGU3SGg5dFE/view?usp=sharing